# ActiveRecord: How to get has_many relation from each record in a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

#### Question

```rb
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :speaker
end

class Speaker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sentences
  # Primary language
  belongs_to :language
  # Secondary languages
  has_many :speaker_languages
  has_many :secondary_languages, through: :speaker_languages, source: :languages
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :letters
  # As a speaker's primary language
  has_many :speakers
  # As a speaker's secondary language
  has_many :speaker_languages
  has_many :secondary_speakers, through: :speaker_languages, source: :speakers
end


class Letters < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
end
```

How could I define an association (or at least a method) on `Sentence` that gets all the possible `Letter`s for a `Sentence`?  As in, all the letters that belong to languages that are either the sentence's speaker's primary language or one of the sentence's speaker's secondary languages.

If it can't be an association and it must be a method, can that method return an ActiveRecord Relation (without any calls to the DB)?

#### What I tried

We can define an instance method on `Speaker` that gets all languages (primary and secondary):

```rb
class Speaker < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def all_languages
    secondary_languages.or(Language.where(id: language_id))
  end
end
```

We could then define an instance method on `Sentence` that gets all the letters for all the languages:

```rb
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def possible_letters
    speaker.all_languages.map(&:letters).flatten.uniq
  end
end
```

But that would result in a call to the DB for each `Language` in `all_languages`.  It would also result in a call to the DB to get the `speaker` (unlike a `has_many :languages, through: :speaker` association).

Comment: do you want the all letters possible for all the languages that a speaker speaks? Or do you want all the letters from the sentences that a speaker has spoken?

Comment: @LesNightingill Given a sentence, I want all letters possible for all the languages that the sentence's speaker speaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @LesNightingill's answer, I came up with the following solution:

```rb
class Language
  ...
  scope :for_sentence, -> (sentence) do
    joins(:speakers, :secondary_speakers)
      .where(speakers: {sentences: sentence}).or(
        where(secondary_speakers: {sentences: sentence})
      ).distinct
  end
end

class Letters
  ...
  scope :for_sentence, -> (sentence) { joins(:language).merge(Language.for_sentence(sentence)) }
end

class Sentence
  ...
  def letters = @letters ||= Letters.for_sentence(self)
end
```

The above solution works, and only requires a single SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT "letters".* 
FROM 
  "letters" 
  INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "letters"."language_id" 
  INNER JOIN "speakers" ON "speakers"."language_id" = "languages"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "speaker_languages" ON "speaker_languages"."language_id" = "languages"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "speakers" "secondary_speakers" ON "secondary_speakers"."id" = "speaker_languages"."speaker_id" 
WHERE 
  (
    "speakers"."id" = ? 
    OR "secondary_speakers"."id" = ?
  ) [[ "id", 
  1], 
  [ "id", 
  1]]
```

Still wondering if there's a more elegant solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the relationships that you have now, but there's a tidier way of expressing the relationships. In my opinion the speaker's primary language should be just a "special case" of all the speaker's languages, so designate with a flag in the `speaker_languages` table. Also, a sentence seems to be more correctly associated with a speaker_language.

I'm suggesting:

```rb
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :speaker_language
end

class SpeakerLanguage
  belongs_to :speaker
  belongs_to :language
end

class Speaker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :speaker_languages
  has_many :languages, through: :speaker_languages

  def primary_language
    joins(speaker_languages: :language).where(speaker_languages: {primary: true}).first
  end

  def secondary_languages
   joins(speaker_languages: :language).where(speaker_languages: {primary: false})
  end
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :letters
  has_many :speaker_languages
  has_many :speakers, through: :speaker_languages
end


class Letters < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
end
```

now the query for letters is simplified. For an instance of `Sentence` we find all the letters from all the languages that the speaker speaks. Since we want letters returned, we query the `Letter` model:

```rb
# letter.rb

def self.all_possible_letters_for_speaker_of_sentence(sentence_id)
  joins(language: {speakers: :sentences}).where(sentence: {id: sentence_id}).distinct
end
```